# Расфасовка по колонкам в CSV

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

Я изучаю Scrapy и делаю первые шаги и не могу понять как можно сделать расфасовку по колонкам при экспорте спарсенных данных в CSV. Например, я делаю парсинг интернет-магазина и там у каждого товара огромное количество характеристик (атрибутов), мне нужно чтобы каждый этот атрибут был в отдельном столбце в CSV файле. Я думаю что нужно парсить все характеристики с HTML тегами в одно поле и потом указав в каком теге находится название атрибута, а в каком значение атрибута дать команду Python раскидать все это по столбцам, название атрибута - это название столбца. Получится каждая характеристика (атрибут) товара в отдельном столбце.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В помощь Вам XPath - String text() — возвращает набор текстовых узлов.

Comment: К сожалению не понял. Мне нужно расфасовать характеристики, каждая в отдельную колонку, учитывая что например на 10.000 товаров их может быть около 100-300 шт. Не буду же я каждую прописывать в коде паука. Нужно просто указать программе в каком теге находится характеристика, в каком ее название, а в каком значение. И дать команду разделить определенный столбец (со всеми характеристиками) на множество других.

Comment: Это сложный путь. Не пугайте количеством товара и характеристиками. Скиньте как Вы находите в  Scrapy характеристики и параметры.

Comment: Предположим это яндекс.маркет https://market.yandex.ru/product--elektronnaia-kniga-amazon-kindle-paperwhite-2018-8gb/218883100/spec?track=tabs . XPath для 1 характеристики //dl[@class='n-product-spec']. Как мне их собрать в одно поле в CSV и потом дать команду при формировании CSV файла разделить эти характеристики по разным колонкам?

Comment: там есть команда cmd 
`scrapy shel  ваш_url`

Comment: я вам помогу - но скиньте этапы Ваших трудов и ошибок